# How do I sort all the values in a file as per the score?

Tags: python

I have a file like this:

```
(u'accept', 4.5553480614894131)
(u'accord', 4.7784916128036237)
(u'acquir', 5.4716387933635691)
(u'adult', 5.4716387933635691)
(u'advisor', 5.4716387933635691)
```

I am looking as sorting this file according to the scores shown above. So, 'adult' & 'advisor'& 'acquir' should be above the previous 3. How can I sort a file as per the score?

So far, I thought of putting them into a dict and somehow sorting it on the scores variable and then writing them in ranked order but I am not receiving it in that format.

```
ele=defaultdict(list)
with open("words.txt","r") as filer:
       for line in filer:
            words, scores= line.strip.split()
            r=sorted(scores,key=lambda key: scores[key], reverse=True)
```

Comment: No. Just no. Do *not* use that format for your file. Just don't. You do not want Python literals as your file format. It is a Bad Idea. Do yourself a favor and use JSON or YAML or some kind of actual standard file format.

Comment: " the implementation is incorrect" Why? What is not working?

Comment: @LutzHorn : I mean the sorting isn't happening because it says string indices must be integers.

Comment: @minks you probably want to `eval()` your lines but I doubt it is a good idea, use json or something like the csv format

Answer (score 0):

First, I would **strongly** encourage you make make the input either JSON-like or tab/comma-separated. Now, your input is very confusing for everyone who has to work with it. But to answer your question:

It would be best to use regular expressions to find the information you want:

```
import re
import operator

s = '''(u'accept', 4.5553480614894131)
(u'accord', 4.7784916128036237)
(u'acquir', 5.4716387933635691)
(u'adult', 5.4716387933635691)
(u'advisor', 5.4716387933635691)'''

allDict = {}
for line in s.split('\n'):
    # Grab the key
    key = re.sub('^\(u\'(\w+)\'.*', '\g<1>', line)

    # Grab the value
    value = float(re.sub('.*(\d+\.\d+)\)$', '\g<1>', line))

    # Put the key, value pair in a dictionary
    allDict[key] = value

# Sort your key-value pairs on the values in reverse order
r = sorted(allDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print(r)
#[('acquir', 5.471638793363569), ('advisor', 5.471638793363569), ('adult', 5.471638793363569), ('accord', 4.778491612803624), ('accept', 4.555348061489413)]
```

Comment: You would have to implement a parser if the the first string can contain `'`, e.g. `(u'accept\'I have a single quote mark', 4.5553480614894131)`.

Comment: @jpmc26, that is true: quotation will make my approach a lot more difficult. However, the example data in the first column from the OP only contained letters (and no special characters like [-'"(*&] etc.), so I kept it simple.